# CSS Grid template areas not working properly

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to re-create a layout using grid-template areas, but it's not working properly and I have no idea why because I think my code is sort of right. So my question is, does someone know how I can properly recreate this layout using `grid-template-areas`?

```css
.a {
  background: red;
  grid-area: a;
}

.b {
  background: green;
  grid-area: b;
}

.c {
  background: aqua;
  grid-area: c;
}

.d {
  background: darkblue;
  grid-area: d;
}

.e {
  background: purple;
  grid-area: e;
}

.f {
  background: orange;
  grid-area: f;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-areas: "a a a a" "b c c c" "b c c c" "b c c c" "b c c c" ". . d d" "e e e e" "e e e e" "e e e e" "f f f f";
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="f"></div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mauro-scheltens/pen/vYrKdwq

The layout I'm trying to rebuild

[image]

Comment: Your HTML (copied across from your Code Pen) has six elements in the `.grid-container`, whereas the image shows 27 elements in the `.grid-container`; how accurately do you want to copy this layout?

Comment: Yeah but the layout has six different elements, which you should be able to do with grid-template-areas. Or am I using it wrong?

Comment: Then you need to [edit] your question to clarify your intent; what is it you're trying to do? What - exactly - are you trying to recreate? Because visually it looks to me like you're asking to use the `.grid-container` to create a layout featuring 27 elements (given that they're implicitly isolated from each other due to the gaps between); so I'm attempting to solve the wrong problem. Please: clarify, disambiguate; help us to help you.

Comment: How do I create this layout with grid-template-areas is my real question haha :p

Comment: Then - as requested - please edit your question to be clear what your question is.

Comment: One of your main mistakes is not providing any size to the divs, or grid areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want every element to be separate rectangle then you need as many div's in html as many elements you want, but if you want to expand rectangles to areas that was set in grid, then just add grid-template-rows to your CSS, like this:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-areas: "a a a a" "b c c c" "b c c c" "b c c c" "b c c c" ". . d d" "e e e e" "e e e e" "e e e e" "f f f f";
  grid-template-rows: repeat(11, 100px);
}
```